# Custom animation: easing out

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, camediatiming

I have successfully created a custom animation in a drawing in a `UIView` by using a repeating `Timer` to increment the alpha of the drawing every few milliseconds.

Now, I want to achieve an easing out animation (deceleration) with my drawing. I would like to do this by firing a new timer with a longer interval every time the `Timer` is called, so that the alpha increments slower, resulting in deceleration.

I know that there is an easeOut animation from `CAMediaTiming`, but I would like to know if there is any built in function to get the decelerating numbers. For example, if I pass in a constant of 10, every time I call the function I can get decelerating numbers like 15, 18, 20, 21, 21.5, etc.

Comment: Swift and Cocoa Touch have built-in methods for animating like this. You don’t need to use a timer at all. I will post an answer soon. In the meantime, can you share the code you have tried?

Answer (score 8):

There is a built-in way to use various sorts of animation curves in standard `UIView` animations.

```
var yourView = UIView() // Or whatever your view might be

var yourView.alpha = 0 // Initial alpha value

// Call the animation method. Note options (which can be an array) which applies an ease-out curve to the animation
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    yourView.alpha = 1.0 // Final value of alpha
}, completion: nil)
```

Other animation curves are available, such as `.curveEaseIn` and `.curveEaseInOut` as well as other options. You can read more about animation options [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/animationoptions).

You can use the completion handler closure to chain animations too.

---

If you are insisting on implementing your own means of animation using a timer (which I would not recommend), post some code so that I can consider  a way to apply a curve to the changing values.